# error when starting NEO4j community instance with offline graph.db

Tags: graph, neo4j, bulkinsert

My graph has approximately 27 million relations and 15 million nodes.
When I try to start neo4j instance with the graph.db database that was created using neo4j import tool, I get the following error:

```
sudo service neo4j status
● neo4j.service - Neo4j Graph Database
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)

Mai 29 17:14:55 ammer-XPS-15-9550 neo4j[21230]:         at 

org.neo4j.kernel.internal.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:75)
Mai 29 17:14:55 ammer-XPS-15-9550 neo4j[21230]:         ... 13 more
Mai 29 17:14:55 ammer-XPS-15-9550 neo4j[21230]: 2017-05-29 
15:14:55.089+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request

 Mai 29 17:14:55 ammer-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Main 
 exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Mai 29 17:14:55 ammer-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Unit entered failed state.

Mai 29 17:14:55 ammer-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Mai 29 17:14:55 ammer-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

Mai 29 17:14:55 ammer-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: Stopped Neo4j Graph Database.

 Mai 29 17:14:55 ammer-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: neo4j.service: Start request repeated too quickly.

  Mai 29 17:14:55 ammer-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: Failed to start Neo4j Graph Database.
```

Comment: Which version are you using ?

Comment: @TomažBratanič I'm using  Neo4j  3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try uncommenting this line in `neo4j.conf`, as I think neo4j-import-tool was not yet upgraded to support 3.2.x version.

```
# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
#dbms.allow_format_migration=true
```

Comment: I have uncommented this line, however, neo4j instance started once but not again.

Comment: you only need this the first time... then you can comment it back